# What subbase generates metric topology?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, metric-spaces, definition

Let metric topology be the topology generated by metric balls of a metrizable space $X$

Is there a subbase $S$ that generates the metric topology?

I am asking because in most textbooks, it seems that people only discuss the base generated by the metric balls, and no attention is paid to subbase and no definition is given.

Thanks

Comment: Well, any base is a subbase, so...

Comment: Are you looking for a subbase which *isn't* a base?

Comment: There's no point in mentioning a (sub)base unless it is actually useful.  See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1820043/86856).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible sub-base would be to take balls of only rational radius.  Any ball of irrational radius can be realized as the infinite union of balls of rational radius.

E.g. $ \ \ B_\pi(x) = B_3(x) \cup B_{3.1}(x) \cup B_{3.14}(x) \cup \cdots$

I hope I've interpreted the definitions correctly.  I'm taking "sub-base" to mean a subset $S \subset B$ that serves as a basis for the metric topology, where $B$ is the basis for the metric topology consisting of all open balls.

Comment: This is even a base for the metric topology.

Comment: Indeed @AlexProvost.  I thought that's what OP was requesting.